# Survey Data to GIS database

Tags: gps, esri-geodatabase, software-recommendations, trimble, land-survey

This is a General Question on a possible workflow for Survey Data directly to ArcGIS

In most GIS/Survey workflows there is a field collection team and backoffice GIS team.

When the availability of high-end mapping devices are there, why can we directly edit a Geodatabase in a Survey device or rather create a GIS feature in Survey device itself, eliminating the CAD and GIS feature creation ?

What my Question is , is there any Survey Device ( Totalstation etc) currently supporting data  editing in GIS format ? Is there any Survey device capable to support a full fledged Geodatabase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcMobile for Windows will connect to GPS units, including RTK, and edit features.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a surveyor, and have never used the software that I am about to suggest, but I understand that Carlson Software may have some strong offerings in this area so I suggest reviewing their **[home page](http://www.carlsonsw.com/)**, if you have not already.